# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__tf2)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, learning-tf, tf2, tf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tried to do tutorial of tf, I got an error as follw.
And same error is occurred when I tried to do the tutorial of tf2.

How can I fix the problem?
Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bjh/catkin_ws/src/learning_tf2/nodes/static_turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tf
  File "/home/bjh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
  File "/home/bjh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
  File "/home/bjh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_py/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__tf2)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326226/importerror:-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-(pyinit__tf2)/) by [joonhyup](https://answers.ros.org/users/43057/joonhyup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue is because tf2_ros was compiled for python2. Detailed discussion [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/259).

To recompile for python3 (melodic):

Install some prerequisites to use Python3 with ROS.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-rospkg-modules python3-empy
```

Prepare catkin workspace

```
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src; cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
wstool init
wstool set -y src/geometry2 --git https://github.com/ros/geometry2 -v 0.6.5
wstool up
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y -r
```

Finally compile for Python 3

```
catkin_make --cmake-args \
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
            -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m \
            -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
```

Do not forget to always source your workspace!

---

Originally posted by [r7vme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39591/r7vme/) with karma: 286 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 26

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joonhyup](https://answers.ros.org/users/43057/joonhyup/) on 2019-06-20**:
I am very appreciate for your help!
It is done!

**Comment by [r7vme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39591/r7vme/) on 2019-06-20**:
Good to hear! @joonhyup can you please accept answer if it helped?

**Comment by [Carls](https://answers.ros.org/users/52876/carls/) on 2020-03-26**:
If your platform is not x86_64, don't forget to change to -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/YOUR_ARCH_NAME-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so

**Comment by [Carls](https://answers.ros.org/users/52876/carls/) on 2020-03-26**:
Also, I've got to install numpy by sudo apt-get install python3-numpy

**Comment by [DJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54053/dj/) on 2020-04-26**:
Hi. I just resolved the PyInit_tf2 error and now I am facing the PyInit_PyKDL error. I tried to do the same way for resolving PyInit_tf2 but it fails when executing `wstool up`. I would like to know is there any way to resolve the PyInit_PyKDL? Thanks.

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-05-20**:
how about if we're using catkin build

**Comment by [jester](https://answers.ros.org/users/25933/jester/) on 2020-07-30**:
libpython3.6m.so does not exist ... it works despite of it

**Comment by [dendrarij](https://answers.ros.org/users/57307/dendrarij/) on 2020-08-04**:
@azerila, catkin build --cmake-args 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m 
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so

**Comment by [Qilos](https://answers.ros.org/users/60189/qilos/) on 2020-12-26**:
Hello, I tried this but when importing tf i get following error:

import tf
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/**init**.py", line 29, in 
from listener import Transformer, TransformListener, TransformerROS
ImportError: No module named 'listener'

**Comment by [mobiiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/68477/mobiiin/) on 2021-02-22**:
this istruction messed up my ros. now my roscore doesnt run and i guess it disables the library path to dynamic libraries. ubuntu 16 and kinetic ros
if ur case is exacly like me. i sokved it by adding following to the last line of bashrc

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [yanjunyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/71641/yanjunyang/) on 2021-03-08**:
Hi @r7vme, I also met the same problem and I compiled it using catkin build. I'm using Ubuntu18.04 and ROS Melodic. The result shows all packages are successfully compiled. After I source the workspace, I still get the same error. Would you mind give me more help and what details I need to provide>

**Comment by [apprentice_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/70809/apprentice_user/) on 2021-06-23**:
the error disappeared when I followed the instructions. but now i get a different error

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

how can ı correct this error

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-07**:
This question is tagged "kinetic", so this user should be using Ubuntu 16. In kinetic, ros uses python2. Why are all of you sending him/her down this path with python3?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

errors like these are also caused by python version problems. so change the first line of the script from
`#! /usr/bin/env python` to  `#! /usr/bin/env python2.7` worked for me

---

Originally posted by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) with karma: 100 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-07-24**:
This worked perfectly. The issue was that by default my python version was python 3.8.10, but ROS melodic requires python 2.7.

Using "which python" in the terminal showed me this.